# pagination custom post type on CP page

Tags: pagination, paginate-comments-links

I know that there are a lot of topics on this question and I've read a lot of them and tried different things. But pagination is still not working. I think it has something to do with the permalink settings.

**The situation**

I have a custom post type called artists which I link to events. On the artist page I show all the events the artist is linked to (they're linked using the posts 2 posts plugin). I'd like to paginate these events. Let's use ACDC as an example artist.

The pagination is showing, and the links point to `root/artist/acdc/page/#` where # is the page number.

If I click on page 2 for example I'm not going to `root/artists/acdc/page/2`. The page does seem to load, but I end up at the same URL showing the first 3 posts (`roots/artists/acdc`). So I don't get a 404.

When I go to `root/artists/acdc?page=2`, the URL becomes `root/artists/acdc/2/`, but it still displays the 3 posts from page 1. This happens when `'format'` is set to `'/page/%#%'` in `paginate_links`. If I then hover the pagination link for page 3, the link becomes `root/artists/acdc/2/page/3`...

**My settings**

- Permalink custom structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`
- I'm using the roots theme which does apply some rewrites, but I as far as I can see there are not rewrites for the permalinks / page structure

**Stuf I've already tried**

- Changed 'show maximum of' setting in WP settings from 10 to 1
- Changed `'paged'` to `'page'` in `$paged`
- Going to the URL `root/artists/acdc/page/2`, no luck as described above
- Going to the URL `root/artists/acdc?page=2`, no luck and weird behavior as described above
- Changed `'format'` in `paginate_links` to `'?page=%#%'`

**My code (which is on the artist custom post type template but will eventually be stored in functions.php**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'connected_type' => 'artists_to_events',
    'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'custom_date',
    'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$big = 99999999;

echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'show_all' => false,
    'end_size' => 2,
    'mid_size' => 3,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => 'Vorige',
    'next_text' => 'Volgende',
    'type' => 'list'
));
```

Because of the weird URL behaviour I don't really know where the problem lies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Since I'm on a single (custom) post page, WP redirects back to the root of the URL. I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073126/wordpress-page-wont-paginate).

The solution (copied from the post on SO) was adding this to the functions.php:

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical','pif_disable_redirect_canonical');

function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
if( is_singular()) {
    $redirect_url = false;
}
return $redirect_url;
}
```

I've removed  `&& in_category('PLACE CAT ID HERE')` from the original code in the post to tailor to my situation.